# Product page: There has been an error processing your request

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've recently upgraded to Magento 1.9. After solving some problems, I couldn't find a solution for this issue.

Magento throws the following error when trying to navigate to a product page:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Invalid method DerModPro_BasePrice_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/design/frontend/tm_themes/theme350k/template/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml(27): Varien_Object->__call('displayProductS...', Array)
#1 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/design/frontend/tm_themes/theme350k/template/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml(27): DerModPro_BasePrice_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Simple->displayProductStockStatus()
#2 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/kunden/329924_...')
#3 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/tm_the...')
#4 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_type_av...', true)
#8 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/design/frontend/tm_themes/theme350k/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(95): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_type_av...')
#9 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/kunden/329924_...')
#10 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/tm_the...')
#11 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#15 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#17 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/design/frontend/tm_themes/theme350k/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(70): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#18 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/kunden/329924_...')
#19 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/tm_the...')
#20 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#24 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#25 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#26 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#27 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#28 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#29 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#30 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(381): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#31 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/app/Mage.php(687): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#32 /kunden/329924_40211/magento19/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#33 {main}
```

I know that the problem is happening because of the new theme i just installed (theme350k).

Does anyone have an idea why this occurs?

Thanks

Comment: tried refresh magento cache?

Comment: Yes I already did that. No success

Comment: your DerModPro_BasePrice module have problem, no one can help you unless you post the relevant codes.